# How to create directory structure inside single Elasticsearch Index?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Currently I have access to single Elasticsearch Index. I have data coming from different teams and I have to organize this data under same Elasticsearch index.

What exactly I need to create is

**Project_XYZ** (Index or main folder)
|---- **Project_XYZ_Development** (Sub Index or sub folder )
|---- **Project_XYZ_Testing**  (Sub Index or sub folder )
|---- **Project_XYZ_Production**  (Sub Index or sub folder )

I have data generated from three different teams and data should go into specific folders under same project (Elasticsearch Index). So that I can create different dashboards to these teams.

Please help me in creating this directory structure inside single index.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for namespacing indices, But you can achieve the same effect by having a `team` field in mapping which will contain the team name.

Then different dashboards can filter by the team